# Gradient material separate z axis and x axis

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, axis

I made a gradient material shown in the picture.

[image]

It should fade out on Z axis.

But on the actual mesh that I applied the texture on. The color faded out to Y axis instead of Z axis.

[image]

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: You seem to be using some cylinder object as texture coordinate origin, that cylinder object may be rotated in relation to the tree. Either remove the object from the *Texture Coordinates* node, clear its rotation, or apply the rotation. You also don't need to duplicate your gradient node setup for each shader. They seem identical, so you can plug the same *Gradient Ramp* to both the *Diffuse* and *Glossy* nodes

Answer (score 0):

Texture Coordinates then Mapping node connected to your gradient texture. Just play with the rotation and you'll be all set.